# How do I use functions from a different subdirectory in python with a virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-venv

I have a simple test project with the following file structure:

```
- Modules
    - .venv
    - code
        - main.py
    - package
        - __init__.py
        - mod.py
```

#### mod.py

```
def add(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1 + arg2)
```

#### main.py

```
from package.mod import add
add(1,2)
```

`__init__.py` is empty.

I want to run `add()` from main.py but when I try it doesn't let me import it saying:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'`

Now, I've seen some other posts about modifying the `PATH` variable at run-time which I tried and it didn't work. I suspect it's because none of these solutions used a virtual-environment.

Comment: How do you execute the code?

Comment: You have a directory `.venv` but your code is not in it, so you have the same situation as without a virtual environment.

Comment: Missing a `..` before the import. `from ..package.mod import add` That will use relative paths. To use absolute paths, `from Modules.package.mod import add`

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim I tried both of those solutions and neither worked for me. The first one gave me `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` and the second `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Modules'`

Comment: `code`, not `Modules`, is in your module search path when you execute `main.py`.  The simplest fix (without properly install your package in your virtual environment) is to just move `main.py` up one directory, so that `Modules` *will* be in your search path when you execute `main.py`.